# Understanding a passage in this matrix equation with the Hadamard product

Tags: matrix-equations, hadamard-product

i was reading the [flipout paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.04386.pdf)  and i stumbled over this passage. I will summarize the main point here:

$x_n$ are the inputs, $W$ is the matrix of the weights. such matrix can be decomposed as the sum of matrix of  the mean values $\bar W$ and the perturbation matrix $\widehat \Delta W$. $r_n$ and $s_n$ are vectors of +1 and -1

the  relation between $y_n$ and $x_n$  is written as

$$y_n =\phi(W^{T}x_n)= \phi((\bar W + \widehat \Delta W  \circ r_n s_n^T )^T x_n)= \phi (\bar W^T x_n +(\widehat{\Delta W}^T(x_n \circ s_n))\circ r_n)$$

where $\circ$ denotes element-wise multiplication.

1. What property has been used in the last passage to transform the equation?
2. I wanted to report this equation but i am using a different notation ($y_n =\phi(W x_n)$), how does it change?

Comment: The formula in the paper is plainly wrong. A few quick tests with small ${\mathbb R}^{5}$ vectors in Matlab/Julia easily demonstrate this.

Comment: @greg how can it be wrong, flipout is implemented in tensorflow. maybe i made some error when i wrote it here. did you check the formula in the paper ?